# Update to twitter api 1.1 in flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, twitter, flash-builder

I build an app with **Flash Builder 4.6** which displays the timeline of a specified user. Since twitter updated their api to version 1.1 I just can't seem to get it to work. According to the `dev. site` i had to use  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json, with the parameters include_enties an screen_name.

When I test the operation it says:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

1. How do I get this to work with Flash Builder? I just want to display the timeline; not edit or post things on it.
2. Must I send some form of authentication from within my code (and if so, an example would be higly appreciated)? Or is it possible to take care of this from within the twitter app (on https://dev.twitter.com/apps/myapp)?

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a little mini-lib that works with app-only authentication (which is what you need the read the timeline):

https://github.com/denisdanielyan/as3-Application-Only-Twitter

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I couldn't get it to work. Have you got some other running examples, or pherhaps a more detailed instruction on how to implement the code and library? Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: When testing the example app, did you enter your consumer key and consumer secret (read the readme for more details) in the file "Mobile Flex Twitter Sample/src/views/MainHomeView.mxml"?

Comment: Yes I did put in the keys. the network monitor doesn't show any activity when I run the app (it makes no connection), so that could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. Got it to work. I will leave a message if all works wel. Thanks!

Comment: so what was the Problem? Anything that I might add to the documentation?

Comment: When I imported the files, FB didn't recognize it as a mobile project. Also it kept saying some .as connection was lost. I just made a new mobile project, copied all the code in the right files, reconnected the lib and it worked. the only two problems I am facing now is how to display images that are inside the tweets (the path 'data.entities.media.media_url' doesn't seem to work. The other is that when I test without an internet connection there is an actionscript error saying there's an unhandled IOerror.

Comment: Anyway; your script is so good, that I was able to fetch the timelines from three different users with the same two keys! I don't think this is supposed to be possible, or is it because I'm at a local machine?

Comment: thanks, did you open the project with fb 4.6 or which application? I think you should be able to open any number of connections (what ios/android allows) up to the twitter limit (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits)

Comment: If I may bother you again: my biggest problem now is that I can't seem to get the 'data.entities.media.media_url' data. It returns nothing; but 'data.user.profile_image_url' works fine (tested it by pasting the code in the label/text= field and it came up with the string). Also added 'include_entities' to the _twitter.request; makes no difference (as it shouldn't). Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: If you want the embedded images, `entities.media[].expanded_url` is where you should look. The length of the media array is stored in `entities.media.length`. It seems to me that the twitter API changed substantially between 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: It did change a lot! This is driving me nuts. Can you point me in the right direction? This doesn't work, the image doesn't show up:  <s:List id="list" top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" dataProvider="{tweets}">
  <s:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
    <s:ItemRenderer>
     <s:BitmapImage source="{data.entities.media.expanded_url}" left="0" width="60" height="60"/>
     <s:Label text="{data.text}" left="65" right="5" top="5" bottom="5"/>
    </s:ItemRenderer>
   </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>

Comment: I think you need to add the indes to `data.entites.media` as there can be more than one image. from the top of my head, this should be something like this: `for(var i:uint=0; i < data.entities.media.length;++i){ var imgSrc:String = data.entites.media[i].expanded_url;}`or just `data.entities.media[0].expanded_url`if you only want to display the first image

Answer (score 0):

See [Pin based authorization for Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization).

For the authorization process itself see [Authorizing request](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I am kind of a noob here. Do you know of any tutorial or documentation on how to implement this in flex? I was hoping it would just be a matter of changing some parameters but it looks like this is going to be a real nightmare.